# How to install Sierra Wireless Ubuntu 16.04 Dell Latitude

Tags: networking, dell, modem, 4g

I have a dell latitude e7470 laptop, I have a 4g sierra wireless modem installed. In windows 7 modem works. On ubuntu 16.04 lts is visible in command output but not working:

output of `lsusb`:

```
lsusbBus 002 Device 002: ID 413c:81b6 Dell Computer Corp.
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0a5c:5805 Broadcom Corp.
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:57c3 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

output of `usb-devices`:

```
T:  Bus=02 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=04 Cnt=01 Dev#=  2 Spd=5000 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 3.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS= 9 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=413c ProdID=81b6 Rev=00.06
S:  Manufacturer=Sierra Wireless, Incorporated
S:  Product=DW5811e Snapdragon™ X7 LTE
S:  SerialNumber=LF62970755041014
C:  #Ifs= 4 Cfg#= 1 Atr=a0 MxPwr=504mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=(none)
I:  If#= 2 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=(none)
I:  If#= 3 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=(none)
I:  If#= 8 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=(none)
```

Do you have any idea to run the modem?

**EDIT**

I changed to:

```
ACTION!="add|change", GOTO="mbim_to_qmi_rules_end"
SUBSYSTEM!="usb|drivers", GOTO="mbim_to_qmi_rules_end"
# load qmi_wwan module
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", \
ATTR{idVendor}=="413c", ATTR{idProduct}=="81b6", \
RUN+="/sbin/modprobe -b qmi_wwan"
# force Dell WWAN 5809e to configuration #1
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", \
ATTR{idVendor}=="413c", ATTR{idProduct}=="81b6", \
ATTR{bConfigurationValue}="1"
# add the new id in the qmi_wwan driver
SUBSYSTEM=="drivers", \
ENV{DEVPATH}=="/bus/usb/drivers/qmi_wwan", \
ATTR{new_id}="413c 81b6"
# load qcserial module
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", \
ATTR{idVendor}=="413c", ATTR{idProduct}=="81b6", \
RUN+="/sbin/modprobe -b qcserial"
# add the new id in the qcserial driver
SUBSYSTEM=="drivers", \
ENV{DEVPATH}=="/bus/usb-serial/drivers/qcserial", \
ATTR{new_id}="413c 81b6"
LABEL="mbim_to_qmi_rules_end"
```

But now I have this:

output od usb-devices

```
I:  If#= 3 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=(none)
T:  Bus=02 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=5000 MxCh= 6
D:  Ver= 3.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=03 MxPS= 9 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0003 Rev=04.08
S:  Manufacturer=Linux 4.8.0-46-generic xhci-hcd
S:  Product=xHCI Host Controller
S:  SerialNumber=0000:00:14.0
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub
T:  Bus=02 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=04 Cnt=01 Dev#=  2 Spd=5000 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 3.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS= 9 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=413c ProdID=81b6 Rev=00.06
S:  Manufacturer=Sierra Wireless, Incorporated
S:  Product=DW5811e Snapdragon™ X7 LTE
S:  SerialNumber=LF62970755041014
C:  #Ifs= 4 Cfg#= 1 Atr=a0 MxPwr=504mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=(none)
I:  If#= 2 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=qmi_wwan
I:  If#= 3 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=qmi_wwan
I:  If#= 8 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=qmi_wwan
```

And it still does not work, unless the driver is missing?

**Edit**

If I load only qcserial mobile broadband (modem) is visible in system, but i cant connect to Orange.

[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJZXZ.jpg)

output of usb-devices:

```
T:  Bus=02 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=04 Cnt=01 Dev#=  2 Spd=5000 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 3.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS= 9 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=413c ProdID=81b6 Rev=00.06
S:  Manufacturer=Sierra Wireless, Incorporated
S:  Product=DW5811e Snapdragon™ X7 LTE
S:  SerialNumber=LF62970755041014
C:  #Ifs= 4 Cfg#= 1 Atr=a0 MxPwr=504mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=(none)
I:  If#= 2 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=qcserial
I:  If#= 3 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=qcserial
I:  If#= 8 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=qcserial
```

Comment: What did you end up figuring out with this? I had a similar problem...

Answer (score 1):

so this post https://andidittrich.de/2015/12/ubuntu-15-10-with-dell-wireless-5570-hspa-42mbps-mobile-broadband-card.html talks you through a solution

1) `apt-get install libqmi-utils`

2) `gksudo gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/99-dell5570.rules`

.... that assumes gedit is installed as a text editor; you will be creating a new file and you paste all the text in the above post that they recommend into your new file

3) **but you must change the ID of the example; to yours**;

so where it says `ATTR{idProduct}=="81a3"`

then you must change each example to `ATTR{idProduct}=="81b6"` ..cos that is yours ..

; SAVE; CLOSE; REBOOT ........... any joy?

Comment: And it still does not work, unless the driver is missing?

Comment: will use answer

Answer (score 0):

you show 
`I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=(none)
I:  If#= 2 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=qcserial
I:  If#= 3 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=qcserial
I:  If#= 8 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=qcserial`

whereas the guide shows 
`I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=qcserial
I:  If#= 2 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=qcserial
I:  If#= 3 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=qcserial
I:  If#= 8 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=qmi_wwan`

and http://www.0xf8.org/2015/07/dell-wireless-5809e-support-in-linux-a-followup/
gives the same profile as the guide 
`I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=(none)
I:  If#= 2 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=qcserial
I:  If#= 3 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=qcserial
I:  If#= 8 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=qmi_wwan`

so more digging needed to understand that; you did install libqmi-utils?

Comment: yes i have already installed libgmi-utils. How can I setup this configuration?

Comment: "yes i have already installed libgmi-utils" .. you did mean libqmi-utils and you have libqmi-glib packages installed?

Comment: lkddb usb 413c 81b6 .. .. .. .. .. .. 0000 ffff : CONFIG_USB_NET_DRIVERS CONFIG_USB_NET_QMI_WWAN : drivers/net/usb/qmi_wwan.c # in 4.11-rc+HEAD                       so it seems your device will be recognised and supported in the 4.11 kernel .... due soon      http://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/USB_NET_QMI_WWAN.html this thread on the qmi_wwan module lists your device

Comment: goodness this site gets confusing to me as edited answers are added in earlier posts; I now see you have either had all Driver=qcserial or Driver=qmi_wwan ...whereas the successful have a mix; this link http://www.0xf8.org/2015/07/dell-wireless-5809e-support-in-linux-a-followup/ gives all the details of what needs to be done by the system, and how it does it

Comment: reading more of the above links; and associated links; makes me think a new kernel might be the best! I do not know how trusting you are of these things but http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/02/ukuu-easy-way-to-install-mainline-kernel-ubuntu ... the GUI ukuu certainly seems to make installing a trial kernel more easy; and allows its removal too; 4.11 is at release 6 so not far from being blessed as stable; one could suggest to you that you try it

Comment: in new rc kernel 4.11 driver is loading automaticly, but still not working. I have information: Mobile Broadband is not enabled. Field where is displayed name of hardware is blank

Comment: what tells you driver is loading automatically please; what does usb-devices give now .. wondering if it now shows the mix of qcserial and qmi_wan .......... I wonder if any of the steps in this thread https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/519607-LTE-modem-on-Dell-Precision-3510 would be of value to you; you do seem a step further on, if the driver is loading